# How many headings does a user add to answers?

Tags: support, data-explorer, formatting

I wonder whether SEDE could figure out how many headings (`#`, `##`, ...) a user uses in their answers.

I came up with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1634154/1992251/answers-with-headlines-of-user)

```sql
SELECT  
  Id AS [Answer],
  LEN(Body) AS [Length]
FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId=2 AND OwnerUserId=##uid##
AND Body LIKE '%# %'
```

but it also matches text like `C#`.

I thought of adding a newline `'%\n# %'` or `'%'+CHAR(10)+'# %'` but that just returns no results anymore.

Comment: The `Body` appears to be rendered HTML, so you should be looking for `<h1>` through `<h6>` elements, not the Markdown for them (which would be incomplete, as they could have been entered as raw HTML in the user input).

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1634212/number-of-headers-in-answers?UserId=480982) is an attempt, which I think avoids `<h1>` and friends in code blocks (those seem to be stored as `<code>&lt;h1&gt;...`) – I always forget how those are rendered. Counting headings is simply done by replacing them with empty strings and comparing the resulting string lengths.

[image]